# How to get assembly reference of started process?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

I have started a process with help of below code.

```
Process p = Process.Start(@"H:\MyProjects\LyncExtension\Sample\bin\Debug\Sample.exe");
```

My question is: how to get assembly reference from above statement.

Pls help me

Comment: Can you explain what you think "assembly reference" means and what you would like to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't.  `Start` runs more than .NET applications.  You could use `Assembly.Load` independently to try to load the binary...